# Java GUI programming strategy?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, methods

Java Beginner.

Hi, I haven't got any much experience with GUI programming. So I'm after some hints on how to tackle this next project. Hopefully I can explain myself well enough.

[image: plan]
<sub>(source: [mobilehomeservicesltd.com](http://mobilehomeservicesltd.com/2010images/decking/mhs10.jpg))</sub>

(see above photo as a reference)
This GUI aspect of my program will be a 2D - Birds-eye-view of a static caravan and veranda/balcony made with basic shapes. So typically the caravan will be represented by a rectangle (just a rectangle, ignore the fill in diagram). Sometimes static caravans have shaped fronts so that would be represented by a polygon as opposed to a rectangle. All in scale dependant on the users input, as all caravans have their individual dimensions.

After the caravan unit is in place I then need to draw another polygon surrounding the caravan representing the balcony/veranda, all to scale. Understand so far?? Good. Here comes the challenge part (for me anyway).

On the polygon representing the balcony I need to be able to draw lines to represent the decking that will be nailed down as a surface (like the diagram above). Now because the caravan could possibly have a shaped front, the decking must follow the shape of the caravan. In other words, if the caravan has an oval or angled front the decking will have to be cut to follow that shaped.

Without boring you all too much with detail. The idea is to let the user decide whether they want the decking fitted in such a way that its running in the same direction as the caravan, or against. Once the user has decided I will then attempt to calculate from the drawing (as it will be to scale) how many full lengths of decking will it take to build this veranda (among various other items).

Now my knowledge is limited on GUI, but I'm up to scratch with panels and drawing lines, rectangles, polygons etc... My original idea was to manually draw the caravan using the g.drawLine method, same with the veranda and then base my calculations on pixel counting to calculate all the various components.

Am I out of my depth attempting this, or is this something relatively easy to program?? Is there a more efficient way of doing this that I should look up before attempting this?

Comment: Are you saying you're not experienced with *Java* GUI programming, or GUI programming in general?  I don't think your "hard part" will actually be the hard part.  Having the program itself know whether the decking is running against or with, and having it assume the same shape, will be easy.  Creating all the Swing components around these concepts that allow the user to interact with the shapes (via buttons, drag-and-drop, whatever method you want to use) will be more difficult. :)

Comment: GUI programming in general. I've basically been taught by a beginners book and it was far from being a comprehensive guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is achievable, but its not the simplest of tasks. But don't let that slow you down.

You'll want to get started by understanding how to draw in Swing.  Take a look at

- [Graphics 2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

You'll also want to be familiar with Swing in general

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

The basic concept with scaling, is assigning a weight to a pixel. The more distance that a pixel is responsible for, the small your image will become